# How to calculate entries of particular column in android studio

Tags: java, android, sql

I want to add the total hours entered in a column in android studio. I have used the following code but still is not working? please someone help me what I have to do next.

**IN DATABASE CLASS**

```
 public Cursor sumHoursColumn(){
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(TillDateCompletedHours) AS myTotal FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    if (c !=null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

**In MainActivity.class**

```
public void calandshow(){
    btshow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Cursor c = mydb.sumHoursColumn();
            int total = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("myTotal"));
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "total hours:-" + total, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

After pressing show button emulator prompts the message as Unfortunately app has stopped.

Comment: Can you post the logcat error?

Comment: There is no any error.

Comment: "Unfortunately, app has stopped" usually means that your app has crashed due to an error and the error will be printed in the logcat. May be the variables mydb or btshow are not been initialized. So check your logcat for the error cause.